# Alarm manager not firing an alarm?

Tags: java, android

I want to start the Alarm Manager when hour and minute are set in the Application, But in my code the alarm is not starting once set.

I am not sure if it is not matching the time with my device or if there is any other issue with my code. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
public class Alarmactivity extends Activity {

AlarmManager alarmManager;
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
private TimePicker alarmTimePicker;
private static Alarmactivity inst;
private TextView alarmTextView;

public static Alarmactivity instance() {
    return inst;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    inst = this;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    alarmTimePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.alarmTimePicker);
    alarmTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alarmText);
    ToggleButton alarmToggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.alarmToggle);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
}

public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
    if (((ToggleButton) view).isChecked()) {
        Log.d("MyActivity", "Alarm On");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentHour());
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentMinute());
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Alarmactivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Alarmactivity.this, 0, myIntent, pendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    } else {
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        setAlarmText("");
        Log.d("MyActivity", "Alarm Off");
    }
}

public void setAlarmText(String alarmText) {
    alarmTextView.setText(alarmText);
}}
```

**AlarmReceiver.java**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    //this will update the UI with message
    Alarmactivity inst = Alarmactivity.instance();
    inst.setAlarmText("Alarm! Wake up! Wake up!");

    //this will sound the alarm tone
    //this will sound the alarm once, if you wish to
    //raise alarm in loop continuously then use MediaPlayer and setLooping(true)
    Uri alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    if (alarmUri == null) {
        alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    }
    Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmUri);
    ringtone.play();

    //this will send a notification message
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            AlarmService.class.getName());
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}}
```

**AlarmService.java**

```
public class AlarmService extends IntentService {
private NotificationManager alarmNotificationManager;

public AlarmService() {
    super("AlarmService");
}

@Override
public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    sendNotification("Wake Up! Wake Up!");
}

private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    Log.d("AlarmService", "Preparing to send notification...: " + msg);
    alarmNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, Alarmactivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder alamNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this).setContentTitle("Alarm").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setContentText(msg);


    alamNotificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    alarmNotificationManager.notify(1, alamNotificationBuilder.build());
    Log.d("AlarmService", "Notification sent.");
}}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Alarmactivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".AlarmService"
        android:enabled="true" />

    <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" />
</application>
```

Comment: Do you get notification or toast at the specified time of the alarm?

Comment: I want notification with alarm tone in specified time.

Comment: I am asking, presently do you get notification at the set time?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me:

**MainActivity.class**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    AlarmManager alarmManager;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private TimePicker alarmTimePicker;
    private static MainActivity inst;
    private TextView alarmTextView;

    public static MainActivity instance() {
        return inst;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        inst = this;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        alarmTimePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.alarmTimePicker);
        alarmTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alarmText);
        ToggleButton alarmToggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.alarmToggle);
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    }

    public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
        if (((ToggleButton) view).isChecked()) {
            Log.d("MyActivity", "Alarm On");
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentHour());
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentMinute());
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        } else {
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
           // setAlarmText("");
            Log.d("MyActivity", "Alarm Off");
        }
    }
}
```

**AlarmReceiver.class**

```
    public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        //this will update the UI with message
        MainActivity inst = MainActivity.instance();
        //inst.setAlarmText("Alarm! Wake up! Wake up!");

        //this will sound the alarm tone
        //this will sound the alarm once, if you wish to
        //raise alarm in loop continuously then use MediaPlayer and setLooping(true)
        Uri alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
        if (alarmUri == null) {
            alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        }
        Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmUri);
        ringtone.play();

        //this will send a notification message
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                AlarmService.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

**AlarmService.class**

```
    public class AlarmService extends IntentService
{
    private NotificationManager alarmNotificationManager;

    public AlarmService() {
        super("AlarmService");
    }

    @Override
    public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        sendNotification("Wake Up! Wake Up!");
    }

    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        Log.d("AlarmService", "Preparing to send notification...: " + msg);
        alarmNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification myNotication;

        Intent intent = new Intent("com.rj.notitfications.SECACTIVITY");

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 1, intent, 0);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext());

        builder.setAutoCancel(false);
        //builder.setTicker("this is ticker text");
        builder.setContentTitle("Alarm Notification");
        builder.setContentText("Alarm Playing");
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.mail2);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setOngoing(true);
        builder.setSubText("This is subtext...");   //API level 16
        builder.setNumber(100);
        builder.build();

        myNotication = builder.getNotification();
        manager.notify(11, myNotication);

    }
}
```